# usps credentials

Tags: asp.net, usps

i am developing shopping cart site in which i want to use USPS(united states postal service)for shipping.can anybody know the fields which are to be required for this service.

Answer (score 2):

Full details on the USPS API can be found here:

- [USPS Web Tools](http://www.usps.com/webtools/)

The fields that are required depend on which service you are using.  The parcel tracking service, for example, requires only a username and tracking ID.